Terraform Nested or For Loops to provision Azure Resources
So I have a Terraform locals.tf file which has the below content to represent a set of environments I intend to deploy to:
locals {
    environments = [
    "sandbox", 
    "test", 
    "prod"]
}

I also then have a monitor.tf file which references the Terraform module of the Azure Monitor Alert resource I wish to provision and is given as follows:
# Create Alert
module "azurerm_monitor_alert" {
  source   = "git::https://.../.../_git/module-tf-azurerm-monitor-alert"
  for_each = local.monitor_alerts[var.environment]
  alert               = each.value
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
  tags = {
    dept = "infra"
  }
  depends_on = [ 
    azurerm_resource_group.alerts_resource_group
  ]
}

I then have a local_alerts.tf file which implements the module to provision the required resources for each of the target environments, non-prod in this case, using the below terraform configuration.
locals {

      monitor_alert_webhook_service_name = "customer-orders"

            monitor_alerts = {

                **SANDBOX** = {
                  orders_failure = {
                    alert_type                        = "metric"
                    name                              = "${["azure_monitor_log_search_alert"]}-rx-failures"
                    resource_group_name               = local.alerts_resource_group
                    location                          = var.location
                    description                       = "Sandbox - One or more calls have failed"
                    scopes                            = [data.azurerm_application_insights.service_app_insights.id] 
                    enabled                           = true
                    evaluation_frequency              = "PT1M"
                    severity                          = 1
                    target_resource_type              = "Microsoft.Insights/components"
                    criteria = [
                      {
                        metric_namespace = "Azure.ApplicationInsights"
                        metric_name = "Submission Failures"
                        aggregation = "Count"
                        operator = "GreaterThan"
                        threshold = 0
                        skip_metric_validation = false
                      }
                    ]
                    
                    action = [
                      {
                        action_group_id = try(module.azurerm_monitor_action_group["rx_engineers"].action_group.id, "")
                        webhook_properties = {
                          service = local.monitor_alert_webhook_service_name
                        }
                      }
                    ]

                }

                **TEST** = {
                  orders_failure = {
                    alert_type                        = "metric"
                    name                              = "${["azure_monitor_log_search_alert"]}-rx-failures"
                    resource_group_name               = local.alerts_resource_group
                    location                          = var.location
                    description                       = "Test - One or more calls have failed"
                    scopes                            = [data.azurerm_application_insights.service_app_insights.id] 
                    enabled                           = true
                    evaluation_frequency              = "PT1M"
                    severity                          = 1
                    target_resource_type              = "Microsoft.Insights/components"
                    criteria = [
                      {
                        metric_namespace = "Azure.ApplicationInsights"
                        metric_name = "Submission Failures"
                        aggregation = "Count"
                        operator = "GreaterThan"
                        threshold = 0
                        skip_metric_validation = false
                      }
                    ]
                    
                    action = [
                      {
                        action_group_id = try(module.azurerm_monitor_action_group["rx_engineers"].action_group.id, "")
                        webhook_properties = {
                          service = local.monitor_alert_webhook_service_name
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                }

                **PROD** = {
                  orders_failure = {
                    alert_type                        = "metric"
                    name                              = "${["azure_monitor_log_search_alert"]}-rx-failures"
                    resource_group_name               = local.alerts_resource_group
                    location                          = var.location
                    description                       = "Prod - One or more calls have failed"
                    scopes                            = [data.azurerm_application_insights.service_app_insights.id] 
                    enabled                           = true
                    evaluation_frequency              = "PT1M"
                    severity                          = 1
                    target_resource_type              = "Microsoft.Insights/components"
                    criteria = [
                      {
                        metric_namespace = "Azure.ApplicationInsights"
                        metric_name = "Submission Failures"
                        aggregation = "Count"
                        operator = "GreaterThan"
                        threshold = 0
                        skip_metric_validation = false
                      }
                    ]
                    
                    action = [
                      {
                        action_group_id = try(module.azurerm_monitor_action_group["rx_engineers"].action_group.id, "")
                        webhook_properties = {
                          service = local.monitor_alert_webhook_service_name
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                }
    
}


Finally, in my local_alerts.tf file, rather than have multiple instances of the same block of code to represent each environment (there are far more than the 3 I've listed by the way), I'd like to have one single block which I can reference iteratively using a nested for_each and/or for loop, to then create the monitor alert resource for each of my target environments, referenced in the initial locals.tf file. Any suggestions or examples to show how I could achieve this?

Define the environment configurations, including descriptions and locations, in your locals.tf file. Use a loop (for_each) to reference the action group in the Azure Monitor alerts block to create alerts in three environments, instead of specifying redundant code for the same requirement.


Terraform Nested or For Loops to provision Azure Resources

You can create monitor alerts for multiple environments by using utilize for_each and for loops effectively.
Define your environments using local.environments and each value contains properties such as description and location as per your requirement.
local.tf
locals {
  environments = {
    sandbox = {
      description = "Sandbox - One or more calls have failed"
      location    = "eastus"
    },
    test = {
      description = "Test - One or more calls have failed"
      location    = "eastus2"
    },
    prod = {
      description = "Prod - One or more calls have failed"
      location    = "westus"
    }
  }

  monitor_alert_webhook_service_name = "customer-orders"
}

Main.tf
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_application_insights" "demo" {
  name                = "sampleinsights"
  resource_group_name = "venkatrg"
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example"{
    name     = "venkatrg"
}
resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "rx_engineers" {
  name                = "CriticalAlertsAction"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  short_name          = "p0action"

  email_receiver {
    name          = "sendtoadmin"
    email_address = "admin@contoso.com"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "alerts" {
  for_each = local.environments

  name                = "${each.key}-orders-failure"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  description         = each.value.description
  scopes              = [data.azurerm_application_insights.demo.id]
  enabled             = true
  severity            = 1
  target_resource_type= "Microsoft.Insights/components"

  criteria {
    metric_namespace        = "Azure.ApplicationInsights"
    metric_name             = "Submission Failures"
    aggregation             = "Count"
    operator                = "GreaterThan"
    threshold               = 0
    skip_metric_validation  = true
  }

  action {
    action_group_id = azurerm_monitor_action_group.rx_engineers.id
    webhook_properties = {
      service = local.monitor_alert_webhook_service_name
    }
  }
}


Terraform apply

Once I execute the above Terraform code, the 3 alert rules have been created.



Greatly appreciate the input Venkat, but I'm afraid it doesn't quite provide the desired solution for me. Please note, that I have two tf local code blocks in my example - One is the locals.environment which gives the environment definition and the Second is the locals.monitor_alerts which provides the monitor alert configuration. Both are needed. The logic for my loop should therefore be: For each environment in locals.environment => Create a monitoring alert as configured in locals.monitor_alerts. I therefore think the monitor For loop should be nested in the environments For_Each.

Do you want to iterate over the locals.environments block to create monitor alerts based on configurations specified in locals.monitor_alerts?

Define your locals.tf variables, including environments and monitor alert configurations, and use nested for_each loops to iterate over locals.environments in main.tf. For each environment, iterate over locals.monitor_alerts to dynamically create monitor alert resources based on the specified configurations.

Venkat, yes my requirement is precisely as you've described it in your last two comments.................and also precisely why I'm seeking assistance on this platform for hopefully some Terraform config/code examples of how I can implement it..

I shared the code with the nested loop in the above comments; if that helps to solve your problem, I will share the complete code by updating the answer.

Your for_each loop on the resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "alerts" only references local.environments as far as I can see. There's no reference to my local.monitor_alerts which is what I've been flagging up. The local.monitor_alerts configuration is a definite requirement which cannot be omitted.
